# How to download SAMPLE-AES-CTR encrypted stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, m3u8

Hey is there a way for me to use `ffmpeg` to download the **SAMPLE-AES-CTR** encrypted stream?

When I open the `mp4` file the audio works fine but the video is broken.
[image: video.mp4]

This is the `m3u8` file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="pod_0",START-DATE="2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",DURATION=1294.7935,X-START-OFFSET="0.0"
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES-CTR,KEYFORMAT="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",URI="data:text/plain;base64,AAAAMnBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABISENR18PVtrUn8kOFwjHCeoCI="
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES-CTR,KEYFORMAT="com.microsoft.playready",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",URI="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-16;base64,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"
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES-CTR,KEYFORMAT="PRMNAGRA",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1",URI="data:text/plain;base64,eyJrZXktaWQiOiJkNDc1ZjBmNS02ZGFkLTQ5ZmMtOTBlMS03MDhjNzA5ZWEwMjIiLCJlbWkiOiJjdHIiLCJwcm0iOiJleUpqYjI1MFpXNTBTV1FpT2lKamRISWlMQ0pyWlhsSlpDSTZJbVEwTnpWbU1HWTFMVFprWVdRdE5EbG1ZeTA1TUdVeExUY3dPR00zTURsbFlUQXlNaUo5In0="
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/map.mp4"
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/00_000.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/08_008.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/16_016.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/24_024.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/32_032.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/40_040.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/48_048.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/00/56_056.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/04_064.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/12_072.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/20_080.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/28_088.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/36_096.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/44_104.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/01/52_112.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/00_120.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/08_128.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/16_136.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/24_144.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/32_152.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/40_160.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/48_168.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/02/56_176.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/04_184.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/12_192.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/20_200.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/28_208.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/36_216.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/44_224.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/03/52_232.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/00_240.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/08_248.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/16_256.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/24_264.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/32_272.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/40_280.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/48_288.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/04/56_296.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/04_304.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/12_312.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/20_320.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/28_328.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/36_336.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/44_344.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/05/52_352.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/00_360.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/08_368.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/16_376.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/24_384.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/32_392.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/40_400.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/48_408.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/06/56_416.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/04_424.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/12_432.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/20_440.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/28_448.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/36_456.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/44_464.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/07/52_472.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/00_480.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/08_488.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/16_496.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/24_504.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/32_512.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/40_520.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/48_528.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/08/56_536.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/04_544.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/12_552.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/20_560.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/28_568.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/36_576.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/44_584.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/09/52_592.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/00_600.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/08_608.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/16_616.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/24_624.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/32_632.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/40_640.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/48_648.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/10/56_656.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/04_664.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/12_672.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/20_680.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/28_688.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/36_696.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/44_704.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/11/52_712.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/00_720.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/08_728.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/16_736.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/24_744.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/32_752.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/40_760.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/48_768.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/12/56_776.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/04_784.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/12_792.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/20_800.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/28_808.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/36_816.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/44_824.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/13/52_832.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/00_840.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/08_848.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/16_856.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/24_864.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/32_872.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/40_880.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/48_888.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/14/56_896.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/04_904.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/12_912.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/20_920.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/28_928.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/36_936.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/44_944.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/15/52_952.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/00_960.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/08_968.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/16_976.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/24_984.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/32_992.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/41_000.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/49_008.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/16/57_016.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/05_024.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/13_032.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/21_040.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/29_048.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/37_056.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/45_064.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/17/53_072.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/01_080.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/09_088.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/17_096.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/25_104.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/33_112.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/41_120.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/49_128.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/18/57_136.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/05_144.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/13_152.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/21_160.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/29_168.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/37_176.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/45_184.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/19/53_192.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/01_200.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/09_208.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/17_216.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/25_224.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/33_232.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/41_240.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/49_248.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/20/57_256.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/21/05_264.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/21/13_272.mp4
#EXTINF:8.008,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/21/21_280.mp4
#EXTINF:5.5055,
241b53fa-e44e-458a-910a-5afca4f57e13/90e4-MAIN/02/4250K/00/21/29_288.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="pod_1",START-DATE="2019-01-01T00:21:34.793Z",DURATION=2.002,X-START-OFFSET="1294.7935"
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="f0af7712-2628-470a-8d9d-ae1c66460e1a/4682-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/map.mp4"
#EXTINF:2.002,
f0af7712-2628-470a-8d9d-ae1c66460e1a/4682-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/00/00/00_000.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="pod_2",START-DATE="2019-01-01T00:21:36.795Z",DURATION=4.004,X-START-OFFSET="1296.7955"
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="52b49aba-7ba2-4882-8e67-f6727417eb66/6da0-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/map.mp4"
#EXTINF:4.004,
52b49aba-7ba2-4882-8e67-f6727417eb66/6da0-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/00/00/00_000.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="pod_3",START-DATE="2019-01-01T00:21:40.799Z",DURATION=2.002,X-START-OFFSET="1300.7995"
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="3d498e45-fa9e-4324-b2f8-cac1d3af3e2f/5906-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/map.mp4"
#EXTINF:2.002,
3d498e45-fa9e-4324-b2f8-cac1d3af3e2f/5906-DUB_CARD/02/4250K/00/00/00_000.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

If there is any other information I can give to solve the problem please let me know.

I have tried the following lines, but none of them worked:

```
ffmpeg -i "URL" -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg -i "URL" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```